# Install wordpress in windows server 2003 which already host asp.net website

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I have a server which already host ASP.Net website. I am migrating from blogger to WordPress. So I need to install WordPress on our server. Can we host WordPress on windows server??

Comment: yes. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/05/11/running-wordpress-on-windows-server-2003.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install Wordpress (or any other php application) on a windows server IF php is installed on the server. There are many tutorials on google on how to install and setup PHP on IIS (the Windows web server), but Microsoft actually provides an easy PHP install from their website : [Install PHP on IIS from Windows Web App Gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53)

Wordpress also needs MySQL to work, so that would have to be installed on the server as well.

Your main concern here I guess is whether you have access to the server to install PHP & MySQL:

- If this server is provided by a hosting service, it might not support
  PHP, in which case there's nothing you can do. You'll need to check with the provider whether they support it or not, and if they can install it.
- If you have complete access to the server, you just need to install PHP and MySQL (a bit of configuration will probably be needed - lots of tutorials on google to help you there); then install Wordpress normally as you would on any other kind of server.

PS: *if you install PHP yourself, you should make sure to check which version of IIS you are running (IIS6 on windows 2003? IIS7+ on windows 2008?). IIS6 requires some extra configuration to make everything work, as pointed out in the article linked by Marty in his comment.*

Answer (score 0):

When I first started using Wordpress I used a Windows Server (granted it was shared space by a service provider) and it ran poorly. I switched to a Linux hosting account and it ran much better. Just my two cents based on my experience.